# Record update failure in IO Monad?

Tags: haskell, io, record, monads

I hope you can help me. I am a Haskell noob after years of imperative languages so if I'm making a stupid mistake, please explain it so I can learn.

I have the following data type:

```
data DicomSopInstance = DicomSopInstance {
sopInstancePath :: String,
sopInstanceUid :: String,
sopInstancePk :: Int64,
seriesFk :: Int64,
sopInstanceFrameCount :: Int32,
sourceDicom :: Maybe EncapDicomObject
}
```

I construct instances of this type from the results of a database query. When the results come in the sourceDicom field cannot have any value so I made it a Maybe value. The problem comes when I try to load the EncapDicomObject and update the data type with the result so I don't have to load the EncapDicomObject from disk every single time I want to access it.

The following is the code that is causing the problem. My intent is to test whether the EncapDicomObject has been read from disk, if it has been loaded then use the existing (Just) value, if not (Nothing is detected) then load it and change Nothing to Just. The troublesome line is marked with "****"

```
showImage :: TextCtrl t -> DicomImage -> IO ()
showImage textCtl image = do
  let sopInst = sopInstance image
  let maybeEncapDicom = sourceDicom sopInst
  case maybeEncapDicom of
  Just encapDicom -> do
    showEncapDicomObject textCtl encapDicom (sopInstancePath sopInst)
    return ()
  Nothing         -> do
    eitherDicom <- readDicomFile $ sopInstancePath sopInst
    case eitherDicom of
      Left errorMessage -> do
        infoM "Hastur" $ "Error reading DICOM file: " ++
          (sopInstancePath sopInst) ++ " - " ++ errorMessage
        textCtrlSetValue textCtl $ "*** DICOM: " ++
          (sopInstancePath sopInst) ++ " ***\n"
        textCtrlAppendText textCtl errorMessage
        textCtrlAppendText textCtl "\n*** [End] ***"
        textCtrlShowPosition textCtl 0
        return ()
      Right encapDicom  -> do
      sopInst { sourceDicom = Just encapDicom } -- ****
        showEncapDicomObject textCtl encapDicom (sopInstancePath sopInst)
        return ()
```

If I comment out the marked line then the code compiles but it loads the file every time since it always encounters Nothing. If I uncomment I get the following error:

```
src\Hastur.hs:382:10:
    Couldn't match expected type `IO a'
           against inferred type `DicomSopInstance'
    In a stmt of a 'do' expression:<br>
        sopInst {sourceDicom = Just encapDicom}
```

I interpret this as meaning that the stmt returns a DicomSopInstance instead of IO () but all my attempts to create a function to update the sopInst and return IO () have failed.

What am I missing? Am I trying to do an on-demand load when Haskell's non-strict behaviour would do that for me or have I simply got the wrong design? My attempts to convert sourceDicom to a mutable variable have come to nought as well :(

cheers

James

Comment: In the future please indent your code by four spaces or use the code-button (the one with the ones and zeros), so your code is properly formatted.

Comment: Ack :( AdBlock was hiding a lot of the interface from me. Fixed I hope.

Answer (score 4):

You're not quite understanding the functional paradigm. `sopInst` is defined at the top of your function. It doesn't have mutable references inside -- its value is set in stone. You can't change that value later. Instead, you can assign a name to another thing, which is a changed version of the original one. Try the following, for example.

```
Right encapDicom  -> do
  let newSopInst = sopInst { sourceDicom = Just encapDicom }
  showEncapDicomObject textCtl encapDicom (sopInstancePath newSopInst)
  return ()
```

Note that since things are immutable, there's a great deal of sharing going on. Imagine that your `SopInst` type is a record in C. Conceptually, it has pointers to all its members. When you construct the `newSopInst` then you just get a copy of that record of pointers, with one pointer now pointing to a new value for `sourceDicom` -- the values pointed to by the other fields are shared. This means that this style of programming (at the cost of more indirections -- necessitated by laziness anyway) is much less inefficient than you might fear, and as a bonus, you still have the old `sopInst` hanging around should you need it elsewhere. (If you don't, of course, it will get garbage collected).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think you're probably right in the general sense, I'm still learning.

I understood when I wrote the code that I would be replacing sourceDicom but perhaps not so much that I would be replacing sopInst. I was comfortable with replacing a small structure and garbage collecting the old one.

Comment: *sigh* still getting the hang of this

Perhaps what I should have asked was: "I need to update these objects when I load a file, how can I do this?"

My Haskell is limited but I'd got as far as realising that updating a value overwrites it but that was my intention. I just want to figure out how to keep the changes

Comment: Oh! I see! You want to update the DicomImage that you're passed! Don't do that! Just `return (image {sopInstance = newSopInst})` and give your function a type of `showImage :: TextCtrl t -> DicomImage -> IO DicomImage`. You can always cheat and use real mutable state with an MVar/IORef, but much better to get the hang of the "right" way early on, and only use MVars/IORefs when really necessary (generally, either with concurrency or certain funny types of ffi).